# e(fx)eclipse with eclipse Luna and Java8

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I m trying to use e(fx)clipse with java8 and eclipse Luna on my mac (yosemite).

In a terminal : java -version gives me

> java version "1.8.0_25" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_25-b17) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

In my eclipse.ini I m putting :

> -vm /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java

which points to my java8 folder.
In eclipse I ve set up the java8 jre.

But when I open eclipse I m still getting :

> You are not running your eclipse instance with Java8 ....

I can't get where I am wrong. Any clue?

Thanks.

Comment: -vm and the path must be on separate lines in the eclipse.ini (and must come before any -vmargs)

Comment: I'm not a Mac user but is `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java` seriously the path to the JRE on a Mac? The path sounds like just a browser plugin to me.

Comment: The path for the 1.8 update 25 JDK is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: I had only JRE installed. That was the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue when I had installed JavaFX eclipse plugin in a 32bit eclipse (Luna). It seems, though you have 64bit OS and 64bit JRE/JDK, and you have setup Environment Variables, you will need 64bit Eclipse to run JavaFX under Eclipse.

Hence, make sure you have 64bit Eclipse running on your machine. If it is a 32bit machine, then there won't be any problem as neither we could install 64bit JDK or 64bit Eclipse.

I hope this solves the problem.

Thanks